# ¿Como consultar en una tabla diferente y mostrar la consulta de cada id del jugador?

Tags: php, mysqli

trato de hacer una consulta en una tabla diferente y mostrar el resultado en mi top, pero que pasa este me muestra en todos los jugadores el mismo resultado cuando en si trato de hacer es que muestre el resultado de cada jugador si este tiene o no un **Match**, intente crear una condicion con otra tabla ya que este se podria decir que trabaja con otra tabla que es la que genera ese **Match** ese codigo entonces cuando lo hago me sigue mostrando a todos el mismo resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en todo me muestra el mismo resultado

```
<?php
require_once('conexion.php');
require_once('steam.php');

$dbTable = "amx_bans";
$query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM '.$dbTable) or die ("Error: ".mysqli_error($db));

$por_pagina = 15;

$sql_register = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS registros FROM '.$dbTable.' WHERE 1');
$result_register = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_register);
$total_registros = $result_register['registros'];
if(empty($_GET['pagina']))
{
    $pagina = 1;
}
else
{
    $pagina = $_GET['pagina'];
}
$desde = ($pagina - 1) * $por_pagina;
$total_paginas = ceil($total_registros / $por_pagina);

if(!isset($_GET['pug_index']))
{
    $pug_index = 1;
}
else
{
    $pug_index = $_GET['pug_index'];
}

$query = $db->query('SELECT server_name, bid, player_id, player_ip, ban_created, player_nick, admin_nick, admin_id, admin_ip, ban_reason, ban_length, expired  FROM '.$dbTable.' ORDER BY bid DESC LIMIT '.($pagina == 1 ? 0 : $desde).', '.($pagina == 1 ? 15 : $por_pagina)) or die ("Error en la consulta: ".mysqli_error($db));
?>
<head>
    <title id="titulo">Baneados | Test e-Sports</title>
</head>
<div class="loader" style="display: block;">
    <div class="pag-default">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="title_bans">
    <h1 class="title">
        <span class="icon-stats-dots"></span>
        Betados
    </h1>
    <a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="ActualizarPagBan()" class="actualizar-button">
        <span class="ic-button icon-spinner11"></span>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="comentarios">
    <p>
        "Los jugadores que se encuentran en esta lista son jugadores que fueron betados de la comunidad por un servidor o algun administrador por una razon, si fuiste baneado por un administrador debes subir tu <span>'POV DEMO'</span> a cualquier nube y enviar a un <span>'Fundador, Dueño o Socio'</span> luego de que la demo sea analizada segun el veredicto de la demo se aplica el desbaneo, de lo contrario el jugador no tendra derecho a un desbaneo en la comunidad"
    </p>
</div>
<div class="betados">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th class="thl thr" width="15%">Fecha </th>
                <th class="thnone" width="5%"> </th>
                <th class="thnone title_banlist" width="20%">
                    <span class="icon-user-tie"></span>
                    LISTA DE BANEADOS
                </th>
                <th class="thl" width="20%">Razón </th>
                <th width="10%">Status </th>
                <th width="15%">Fecha de Expiración</th>
                <th class="thr" width="5%">Match </th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            while($top = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
            {
                $diasBaneados = floor($top["ban_length"] / 1440);
                $horasBaneadas = floor($top["ban_length"] / 60);
                ?>
                <tr onclick="DisplayBetado(<?php echo $top['bid']?>)" class="<?php if (($top['bid'] % 2) == 0) { ?>tr_2<?php } else { ?>tr_1<?php } ?>">
                    <td>
                        <?php echo gmdate("d/m/Y - h:i A", ($top["ban_created"] - 14400));?>
                    </td>
                    <td class="avatar">
                        <a target="_blank" href="https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/<?php echo getSteam64($top["player_id"]);?>">
                            <img src="img/default_avatar.jpg" alt="<?php echo $top['player_nick']; ?>">
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="name">
                        <?php echo substr($top['player_nick'], 0, 15) ?>
                    </td>
                    <td><?php echo $top["ban_reason"] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $top["player_id"] ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <?php if ($top['ban_length'] == 0)  { ?>
                            Nunca
                        <?php } elseif ($top['expired'] == 1) { ?>
                            Expirado
                        <?php } elseif ($top['ban_length'] >= 1440) { ?>
                            <?php echo "$diasBaneados" ?> días
                        <?php } elseif ($top['ban_length'] >= 60) { ?>
                            <?php echo "$horasBaneadas" ?> hora
                        <?php } elseif ($top['ban_length'] >= 5) { ?>
                            <?php echo $top['ban_length'] ?> minutos
                        <?php } ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php if ( ! empty($top['pug_hash'])) { // Comprueba si el campo no está vacío y, si no lo está, lo muestra ?>
                            <a><?php echo $top['pug_hash']; ?></a>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                            <span style="color:#999999;">Sin demo</span>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div id="betado_perfil"></div>
    <div class="paginador">
        <ul>
            <?php if($pagina > 1) 
            { ?>                
                <a onclick="PaginadorClickBans(<?php echo $pagina - 1; ?>)">
                    <span class="icon-backward2"></span>
                </a>
                <a onclick="PaginadorClickBans(1)">1</a>
                <li>...</li>
                <?php
            }
            if($pagina >= 5 && $pagina + 5 < $total_paginas) 
            {
                for($i = $pagina - 3; $i <= $pagina + 3; $i++)
                { 
                    if($i == $pagina) echo '<li class=pgselect>'.$i.'</li>';
                    else echo '<a onclick="PaginadorClickBans('.$i.'")>'.$i.'</a>';                       
                }   
            } 
            else if($pagina <= 5)
            {
                for($i = ($pagina > 1) ? 2 : 1; $i <= $pagina + 3; $i++)
                { 
                    if($i >= $total_paginas)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if($i == $pagina) echo '<li class=pgselect>'.$i.'</li>';
                    else echo '<a onclick="PaginadorClickBans('.$i.')">'.$i.'</a>';                       
                }
            } 
            else if($pagina >= $total_paginas - 5) 
            {
                for($i = $pagina - 3; $i <= ($pagina == $total_paginas ? $total_paginas : $total_paginas - 1); $i++)
                { 
                    if($i == $pagina) echo '<li class=pgselect>'.$i.'</li>';
                    else echo '<a onclick="PaginadorClickBans('.$i.')">'.$i.'</a>';
                }                
            }
            if($pagina != $total_paginas) 
                {?>
                    <li>...</li>
                    <a onclick="PaginadorClickBans(<?php echo $total_paginas; ?>)"><?php echo ''.$total_paginas.''; ?></a>
                    <a onclick="PaginadorClickBans(<?php echo $pagina + 1; ?>)">
                        <span class="icon-forward3"></span>
                    </a>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function DisplayBetado(val){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'include/web/sub/betado_stats.php?id=' + val,
                cache: false,
                success: function (html) {
                    $("#betado_perfil").html(html);
                    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#betado_perfil").offset().top},500,function(){
                        ultimoscroll=$(window).scrollTop();
                        animacion=false;
                    });
                }
            });
            return false;
        };
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function PaginadorClickBans(val) {
            $('#content_right').load('include/web/right_content_bans.php?i='+ '&c=1&pagina=' + val);
            return false;
        }
    </script>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ayuda por favor :(

Comment: Ayuda por favor :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en que tienes dos consultas SQL, una con los datos del usuario (`$query`) y otra donde se encuentra el match (`$query2`), pero no existe ninguna relación entre ellas. No hay manera de que la aplicación sepa si existe algún match concreto para un usuario.

Lo correcto sería crear una única consulta SQL que relacione ambas tablas mediante un `LEFT JOIN`, que permitirá cargar todos cada usuario y, si hubiera un match relacionado, también éste. Si no estás familiarizado con ello, aquí tienes la explicación y ejemplos: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Como no has indicado la estructura de la base de datos en la pregunta, es complicado dar una solución concreta, pero deberías comprobar si en la tabla `amx_lge_serverstats` hay algún campo tipo `player_id` que se relacione con el mismo campo de `amx_bans`. Si es así, tu variable $query debería ser algo como (lo he puesto en varias líneas para que lo leas mejor, puedes escribirlo todo seguido):

```
SELECT amx_bans .*, amx_lge_serverstats .pug_index, amx_lge_serverstats .pug_hash
FROM amx_bans
LEFT JOIN amx_lge_serverstats ON amx_lge_serverstats .player_id = amx_bans .id AND amx_lge_serverstats.pug_index = $pug_index
```

Además, ya en el código, sólo tendrías que hacer un par de cambios:

Uno, prescindir de `$query2`, `$query3` y `$pug_info`, que ya no te harán falta.

Dos, cambiar la parte donde muestras el match, que ahora al hacerse sobre el resultado de `$query` se incluiría en la misma variable que el resto (`$top`):

```
<td>
    <?php if ( ! empty($top['pug_hash'])) { // Comprueba si el campo no está vacío y, si no lo está, lo muestra ?>
    <?php echo $top['pug_hash']; ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <span style="color:#999999;">Sin demo</span>
    <?php } ?>
</td>
```

Eso debería servirte.

Luego, dos cosas relativas a tu código:

Es **muy importante** que, por razones de seguridad (evitar inyecciones SQL, ataques XSS...), tengas cuidado con las consultas SQL a las que le pasas variables (en este caso `$pug_index`). Tienes mucha información al respecto, pero aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo funciona: https://devlaz.com/consultas-seguras-en-mysql-con-php

Otra poco importante pero que ayudará a que éste se mantenga mejor: Entiendo que usas la condición `if (($top['bid'] % 2) == 0)` solo para decidir si la clase CSS que cargas es `tr_2` o `tr_1` en la fila de cada usuario. Es mucho más sencillo si, en lugar de incluir el mismo código en las dos partes de la condición, únicamente la incluyes una vez y pones este condicional solo dentro del atributo `class` de la etiqueta `<tr>`:

```
<?php

while ($top = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    
    $diasBaneados  = floor($top['ban_length'] / 1440);
    $horasBaneadas = floor($top['ban_length'] / 60);
    
?>
<tr onclick="DisplayBetado(<?php echo $top['bid']?>)" class="<?php if (($top['bid'] % 2) == 0) { ?>tr_2<?php } else { ?>tr_1<?php } ?>">
    <td>
        <?php echo gmdate("d/m/Y - h:i A", ($top['ban_created'] - 14400)); ?>
    </td>
    <td class="avatar">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/<?php echo getSteam64($top['player_id']); ?>">
            <img src="img/default_avatar.jpg" alt="<?php echo $top['player_nick']; ?>">
        </a>
    </td>
    <td class="name">
        <?php echo substr($top['player_nick'], 0, 15); ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $top['ban_reason']; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $top['player_id']; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php if ($top['ban_length'] == 0)  { ?>
            Nunca
        <?php } elseif ($top['expired'] == 1) { ?>
            Expirado
        <?php } elseif ($top['ban_length'] >= 1440) { ?>
            <?php echo "$diasBaneados" ?> días
        <?php } elseif ($top['ban_length'] >= 60) { ?>
            <?php echo "$horasBaneadas" ?> hora
        <?php } elseif ($top['ban_length'] >= 5) { ?>
            <?php echo $top['ban_length'] ?> minutos
        <?php } ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php if( ! empty($pug_info['pug_hash'])) { // Comprueba si el campo no está vacío y, si no lo está, lo muestra ?>
            <?php echo $pug_info['pug_hash']; ?>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <span style="color:#999999;">Sin demo</span>
        <?php } ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Si te fijas, he hecho un par de cambios también en el código HTML:

En la imagen del avatar incluyes el atributo `alt`, pero no le asignas ningún valor. Puedes incluir, como hice en el ejemplo, el nick del usuario.

He prescindido de la etiqueta `<a>` del campo match, ya que no incluía ningún atributo ni enlace, lo que hace que la etiqueta no tenga sentido.

**Actualización**

Teniendo en cuenta las tres tablas que tienes, tendrías que hacer dos relaciones:

`amx_bans` con `amx_lge_playerstats`, a través de la Id del usuario.

`amx_lge_playerstats` con `amx_lge_serverstars`, a través de la columna `pug_index`.

```
SELECT amx_bans.*, amx_lge_serverstats.pug_index, amx_lge_serverstats.pug_hash
FROM amx_bans
JOIN amx_lge_playerstats ON amx_lge_playerstats.player_steamid = amx_bans.player_id
LEFT JOIN amx_lge_serverstats ON amx_lge_serverstats.pug_index = amx_lge_playerstats.pug_index
```

Comment: Hola buenos días, muchas gracias por responde, gracias por corregir algunas partes del código, acabo de actualizar el post y añadi 2 fotos de las 2 tablas que pasa en la tabla **amx_lge_serverstats** es donde genera ese **pug_hash** y tambien tiene su **pug_index** y en la tabla **amx_lge_playerstats** que es la segunda foto se podria decir que donde quiero que tome los datos ya que en si los 2 tienen el mismo **pug_index** osea es conectar esas 2 tablas y generarle al jugador si este posee o no un **pug_hash**

Comment: en si seria verifica en la 2 tablas que su **pug_index** sea igual para que este le muestre el **pug_hash**, y perdon apenas estoy aprendiendo borre la parte de los query que me dijiste pero como puedo adaptar `SELECT amx_bans .*, amx_lge_serverstats .pug_index, amx_lge_serverstats .pug_hash
FROM amx_bans
LEFT JOIN amx_lge_serverstats ON amx_lge_serverstats .player_id = amx_bans .id AND amx_lge_serverstats.pug_index = $pug_index` al query que queda?

Comment: Estoy intentado de varias formas pero no consigo hacerlo funcionar

Comment: intente hacer que tomara el status y al index pero aun asi me daba el mismo resultado a todos

Comment: La cuestión es que no solo necesitas relacionar las tablas amx_lge_serverstars y amx_lge_playerstats, también tienes que enlazarlas con la tabla que incluías originalmente (amx_bans). En amx_bans tienes un player_id, ¿ese player_id está en amx_lge_playerstats? ¿cómo sabes qué filas de amx_lge_playerstats tienen relación con las de amx_bans? Eso es lo que necesitas saber para generar la consulta.

Comment: Mmm la tabla del **amx_bans** ya es aparte de las otras 2, no se puede hacer nada entonces?

Comment: amx_lge_serverstats y amx_lge_playerstats podrían relacionarse con un LEFT JOIN o un JOIN a secas a través de la columna pug_index que tienen ambas, pero si la base de datos no está estructurada de tal forma que amx_bans se relacione con al menos una de las otras tablas, me temo que no es posible.

Comment: Wa, pero no se le puede hacer que coomo en las 2 genera una **ID** este reprenta por asi decirlo que las 2 estan conectadas entonces en la tabla de **amx_lge_playerstats** genera un steamid a los jugadores no hay forma de relacionar esa steamid con la del **amx_bans**?

Comment: Si existe una columna en amx_bans con el valor del steamid que tienes en una columna de amx_lge_platerstats, podrías relacionarlas por ambos campos, sí.

Comment: si en el amx_bans es este **player_id** pero no se como relacionar ya que no se en si como hacer la funcion con el LEFT JOIN

Comment: He editado la respuesta incluyendo un ejemplo al final de la misma. Ten en cuenta que sólo funcionará si la columna player_id de amx_bans y la columna player_steamid de amx_lge_playerstats tienen el mismo valor.

Comment: pero sigo teniendo la duda de como adaptarlo al query `$query = $db->query('SELECT server_name, bid, player_id, player_ip, ban_created, player_nick, admin_nick, admin_id, admin_ip, ban_reason, ban_length, expired  FROM '.$dbTable.' ORDER BY bid DESC LIMIT '.($pagina == 1 ? 0 : $desde).', '.($pagina == 1 ? 15 : $por_pagina)) or die ("Error en la consulta: ".mysqli_error($db));`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141653/discussion-between-o1dskoo1-and-demiv).

Comment: Ya entro al chat